# LC3 Starting Address of the File

Tags: lc3

For my LC3 assignment, I need to enter x3100 for the starting address of the file, how would I do that? Like what opcode would I need, I am not really sure among the ones we've studied so far.

Answer (score 0):

You would use

```
.ORIG x3100
```

At the beginning of your code. It's called a pseudo-op or assembler directive, because only the assembler uses it.

Comment: But I thought that would be the load address. I have to do both:
• Enter x3000 for the program’s load-address as the first line of the program. 
• Enter x3100 for the starting address of the file

Comment: You'll have to define what your asking then, because in the LC-3 asm language .ORIG is the starting address for that particular file. Are you talking about loading a second file into the simulator, or a sub-routine of code at x3100?